# HTTP GET in VBS

Tags: http, vbscript, request

Is there a way to perform an HTTP GET request within a Visual Basic script?  I need to get the contents of the response from a particular URL for processing.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.open "GET", "http://www.example.com", False
o.send
' o.responseText now holds the response as a string.
```

Comment: Just to add the third bool parameter represents if the call is to be made async  or sync. False value means it will be a synchronous call. Also the open API has two more parameter for authentication to pass Userid and password if it is required by the website being called.

Comment: I'm having problems using this method from Windows 2012, I think that's due to the lot of different versions released by microsoft. I am thinking of using antoher method for make an HTTP Get from vbs, any ideas??

Comment: Simple example for a simple question.  It took me 2 hours to find this, which is all I needed.  Bravo!

Answer (score 41):

You haven't at time of writing described what you are going to do with the response or what its content type is.  An answer already contains a very basic usage of `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` (I recommend the more explicit `MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0` progID) however you may need to do different things with the response, it may not be text.

The XMLHTTP also has a `responseBody` property which is a byte array version of the reponse and there is a `responseStream` which is an `IStream` wrapper for the response.

Note that in a server-side requirement (e.g., VBScript hosted in ASP) you would use `MSXML.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0` or `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` (which has a near identical interface).

Here is an example of using XmlHttp to fetch a PDF file and store it:-

```
Dim oXMLHTTP
Dim oStream

Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")

oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", "http://someserver/folder/file.pdf", False
oXMLHTTP.Send

If oXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write oXMLHTTP.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "c:\somefolder\file.pdf"
    oStream.Close
End If
```

Comment: hey anthony! How would we specify auth keys or request arguments externally? or we can just keep that a part of the url.

Comment: @SushantKhurana: The would depend on what the server is expecting.  You an include additional headers in the request with addHeader method so if you have control of both ends you create some custom "x-myheader" header.   Or you can use a "POST", add a Content-Type header like "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and pass a urlencoded string contianing parameter to the `send` method.  Or as you say include the values in the query string.  It really depends on what you have available to you on the server.

Comment: Yes. I have to do that via a Basic HTTP Authorization header only. Example Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==

Comment: @SushantKhurana@  For basic authorization just specify the username and password as the 4th and 5th parameters in the XMLHttp `open` method call.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the GET request to actually SEND data...

check:
http://techhelplist.com/index.php/tech-tutorials/37-windows-troubles/60-vbscript-sending-get-request

The problem with MSXML2.XMLHTTP is that there are several versions of it, with different names depending on the windows os version and patches.

this explains it:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269238

i have had more luck using vbscript to call

```
set ID = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.visible = 0
IE.navigate "http://example.com/parser.php?key=" & value & "key2=" & value2 
do while IE.Busy....
```

....and more stuff but just to let the request go thru.

Comment: That is just ugly and inefficient, why would you do this? Every time you call this code you are creating an instance of `iexplore.exe` in the background which then calls winsock.dll to handle to the HTTP request, where as the Server HTTP Request objects do this directly with far less overhead.

Answer (score 0):

```
        strRequest = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" " &_
         "xmlns:tem=""http://tempuri.org/"">" &_
         "<soap:Header/>" &_
         "<soap:Body>" &_
            "<tem:Authorization>" &_
                "<tem:strCC>"&1234123412341234&"</tem:strCC>" &_
                "<tem:strEXPMNTH>"&11&"</tem:strEXPMNTH>" &_
                "<tem:CVV2>"&123&"</tem:CVV2>" &_
                "<tem:strYR>"&23&"</tem:strYR>" &_
                "<tem:dblAmount>"&1235&"</tem:dblAmount>" &_
            "</tem:Authorization>" &_
        "</soap:Body>" &_
        "</soap:Envelope>"

        EndPointLink = "http://www.trainingrite.net/trainingrite_epaysystem" &_
                "/trainingrite_epaysystem/tr_epaysys.asmx"



dim http
set http=createObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
http.open "POST",EndPointLink,false
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type","text/xml"

msgbox "REQUEST : " & strRequest
http.send strRequest

If http.Status = 200 Then
'msgbox "RESPONSE : " & http.responseXML.xml
msgbox "RESPONSE : " & http.responseText
responseText=http.responseText
else
msgbox "ERRCODE : " & http.status
End If

Call ParseTag(responseText,"AuthorizationResult")

Call CreateXMLEvidence(responseText,strRequest)

'Function to fetch the required message from a TAG
Function ParseTag(ResponseXML,SearchTag)

 ResponseMessage=split(split(split(ResponseXML,SearchTag)(1),"</")(0),">")(1)
 Msgbox ResponseMessage

End Function

'Function to create XML test evidence files
Function CreateXMLEvidence(ResponseXML,strRequest)

 Set fso=createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set qfile=fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\RajkumarJoshua\Desktop\DCIM\SampleResponse.xml",2)
 Set qfile1=fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\RajkumarJoshua\Desktop\DCIM\SampleReuest.xml",2)

 qfile.write ResponseXML
 qfile.close

 qfile1.write strRequest
 qfile1.close

End Function
```

Comment: You need to have some commenting to supplement your code.