# Curl giving "Invalid UTF-8 JSON" error from CouchDb although JSON is fine? Any ideas?

Tags: json, curl, couchdb

This is slightly different from the question titled "Error about ‘invalid JSON’ with couchDB view but the json’s fine": I am not trying to upload a file only enter a simple document.

The example I am trying to use is actually from O'Reilly's book "CouchDB: The Definitive Guide" and I am pretty sure that I have tried it before and got it to work. Here's the command:

```
curl -X PUT http://username:password@127.0.0.1:5984/albums/6e1295ed6c29495e54cc05947f18c8af -d '{"title":"There is Nothing Left to Lose","artist":"Foo Fighters"}'
```

The database albums exists and the username and password are correct. I have checked this with JSONLint and the JSON is valid and I am at a loss ... presumably there is an issue with the CouchDB server itself but it appears to be running correctly ... any ideas? This is driving me nuts!

Thanks

Comment: what are the response headers saying?

Comment: Have you upgraded your couchdb? I had this problem after an upgrade from 0.10 to 1.0. What happens if you run the test suite?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks guys. Turns out it's a problem with quote escaping. Here's the answer I got from David on the CouchDB user mailing list:

> This is a windows thing regarding
>   quoting - a real PITA. Unfortunately
>   cmd.exe shell on windows doesn't parse
>   this correctly. The rules for when
>   escaping with a "" or a ^" or a \" are
>   a bit vague but this works:
>
> C:\tmp>curl -X PUT
>   http://username:password@127.0.0.1:5984/albums/6e1295ed6c29495e54cc05947f18c8af
>   -d "{\"title\":\"There is Nothing Left to Lose\",\"artist\":\"Foo
>   Fighters\"}"
>   {"ok":true,"id":"6e1295ed6c29495e54cc05947f18c8af","rev":"1-4b39c2971c9ad54cb37e08fa02fec636"}
>
> C:\tmp>
>
> "basically you need to \"escape\" all
>   \"quotes\" within your JSON"

This fixes my problem

Comment: Is there no other way? I mean, escaping quotes seems like a PITA.

Comment: This is a limitation of the shell.  An alternative would be to put the JSON in a file, and use -d @filename

Comment: @Das: I solved it by installing Git. It includes Git Bash with curl.

Comment: @null yes that is another way... another **better** way. Especially since many of us have git already installed. Plus bash has a better color scheme than cmd )

Answer (score 0):

I also met same problem, after searching a while, I found about [Git Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20598096/844005) in other question. Git bash has curl command inside. The git bash is included in Git installer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the escap characterstic **** and also do not forgot to put after -d all things in **""**.
I.e : curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/my_database/"001" -d "**{\"Name\":\"Suresh\",\"age\":\"32\",\"Designation\":\"Associates Manager\"}**"

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I just ran into the same issue.

The solve I used was to use VSCode's terminal instead of Windows CMD. You don't have to put in a bunch of escapes at that point.