# Windows batch How will I call a url and test the returned value?

Tags: windows, url, batch-file, if-statement

I would like to have the url call and if test done as batch,
draft as shell script below, what would the Windows equivilent of the following shell script look like?

```
tmp=$( curl -s "http://server.my.lan/test.php" );

if [ $tmp == "0" ]; then
  # Windows calls 2 next lines, the action I would like if the URL does not return 0
  #net stop "World Wide Web Publishing Service"
  #net start "World Wide Web Publishing Service"
fi
```

What is the Windows equivilent of curl?

Comment: possible duplicate of [steps to setup cURL in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/steps-to-setup-curl-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use curl on Windows you'll have to set it up. See this question: [How do I install/set up and use cURL on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/steps-to-setup-curl-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Download the standalone version of cURL for windows from here: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('curl -s "http://server.my.lan/test.php" ') do set "tmp=%%a"

if "%tmp%" equ "" (
  net stop "World Wide Web Publishing Service"
  net start "World Wide Web Publishing Service"
)
```

Comment: for /f "delims=" %%a in ('echo 0 ') do set "tmp=%%a"
tells me %%a was unexpected at this time.

Comment: @WoundedKnee  Did you executed this in command prompt or in a batch file? It it's the command prompt you need to use single `%`

Comment: Yes, I executed this on the command line, what is the difference between % and %%?