# The Requested Operation has failed- Apache error

Tags: apache, apache2.2

When I'm trying to start the Apache 2.2 server it is showing the following message: **The Requested Operation has failed**

In command Prompt it is showing as follows:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\amth>net start apache2.2
The Apache2.2 service is starting.
The Apache2.2 service could not be started.

A service specific error occurred: 1.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3547.
```

Comment: Something else might be listening on port 80. E.g IIS etc. ([Source](http://serverfault.com/a/513407))

Answer (score 2):

Open run( win + r ) in windows and then type services.msc. Search for Apache service. Double click on the service and select any startup type other than disabled. This should work like a charm.

Comment: This does not help. Startup type has been on "automatic" for years.

Answer (score 1):

Open conf folder then open  httpd.conf file in your text editor.
Find this line:

## Listen 12.34.56.78:80

Listen 80
and change it to

## Listen 12.34.56.78:80

Listen 8080

Then hit save

Answer (score 1):

I have wasted a whole day on figuring out why `curl_init()` threw an undefined-error. Im using Windows, Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.3

After trying to:

1. Install a fresh version of Curl [As described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/how-do-i-install-and-use-curl-on-windows)
2. Enabe Curl in the php.ini file [following this description](http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/enabling-curl-in-php-php-ini-wamp-xamp-ubuntu/)

I still got this error.

**The solution** was to add the directory of the php e.g *c:php/* to the PATH Variable in the Windows environment variables.

```
->Hit the Windows-Key and S 
-> search for "System"
-> go to advanced options(a small window shuld pop up) 
-> hit environment variables 
-> in the **bottom** box scroll until you find "PATH" 
-> select it and hit "edit" 
-> enter the php directory and close the window 
-> reboot your PC
```

Hopefully it will work for you too :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you done any changes in httpd.conf file ? i was also facing same problem in my case i have saved httpd.conf file as txt so due to that i was getting error

Answer (score 0):

Was getting this issue when trying to start Apache with mod_jk. As part of loadmodule in http.conf file LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so was added but in Apache2.2\modules folder mod_jk.so file was not available. Added mod_jk.so file to modules folder and apache started without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did - if you uninstall and reinstall apache via command prompt it

httpd -k unistall/httpd -k install

then it displays the errors

in my case the require all was missing 'granted' at the end of to look like 'require all granted'

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride all

    Require all 

</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your lan ip changed then you would come across this error. In the httpd conf file you to rectify the following:
Listen IP:Port

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error message on Windows Server 2008 R2. I was using SSL and realized that my signer certs, configured in ssl.conf, where placed in the wrong folders on the file system. I placed the certs in the correct spot and the service and Apache was working fine afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried closing World Wide Web services, changing a lot of ports and surfing many forums, and eventually I looked in to Logs=>Apache (error.log) files.

[image: 1]

I saw in this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Directive 'asp_tags' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0

[image: 2]

Then I opened php.ini files in XAMPP. Find with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> `asp_tags=On` line and turn it to `Off`.
All of it then worked.

[image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

It occurs sometimes because of the availability of ports. To make it work you can change the port from 80 to 8080 (first check if the 8080 port is free)

now go to the Apache installation folder then the `conf` folder.
Open the `httpd.conf` file on a text editor (in my case it is Notepad++)

search for `Listen 80`
Replace it with `Listen 8080`

Now restart the Apache again! and hit http://localhost:8080

Answer (score -1):

In my case Apache 2.4 is worked on Win7Pro 64bit. Last week it worked fine but today I was unable to start it as usually. I tried to check logs for errors but no clue. Then I went to Control panel -> Administrative tools -> Services and found there Apache service was disabled!? Click on property, set Startup type to manual and - voila! It started like charm.