# Will this "Requested Operation has Failed" error going to be an issue in the latter part after I'm done installing PHP, phpMyAdmin, & MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to install phpMyAdmin on my Windows 10, I want to create a registration/login form with some back-end stuff like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C--mu07uhQw), but Apache, PHP & MySQL must be installed first in order for phpMyAdmin to work.

I already installed Apache and do some configuration I found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/748117/how-to-manually-install-apache-php-and-mysql-on-windows), when I go to `http://localhost`, the "It Works" message will show, but in the Apache Service Monitor, I'm getting "[The Requested Operation has failed- Apache error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383633/the-requested-operation-has-failed-apache-error)". ([error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnjgm.png)).

I already tried the suggested fix in the post, but nothing works.

My question is, will this "Requested Operation has Failed" error going to be a problem in the latter part after I'm done installing PHP, phpMyAdmin, & MySQL?

Comment: Try looking in your apache log file to see if anything shows up there. The other question you liked seems to indicate that it could be that port 80 is already in use. Are you trying to run multiple instances of Apache, or multiple web servers at the same time?

Comment: I would recommend that you either use something like XAMPP (a ready made package with all the applications you need) or even better, use something like Vagrant to install a virtual linux development server with everything you need.

Comment: @Mike I closed my browser...nothing else use port 80.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Ok, I'm gonna try that.

Comment: @liame Closing your browser does not free up port 80. To do that you need to stop the server running on that port. However Magnus has a point. Go with a ready made package.