# How to open console/window to use CURL command in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using winodws 8.1.
I have installed elastic search, now I want to create an index in elastic search
so,which IDE I can use? or how to open to user CURL command like below?

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/depst/semployee/11' -d '{ "name": "xxxx"}'
```

how to open window which allow to type above command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **cygwin** with the **curl extension** installed or you can - for example - to manualy querying.
You can also install the **plugin head** for elasticsearch wich permit you to test your index, more information about head plugin here:

https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head

Comment: but I want to open window to fire curl command, let say for window we can open command prompt like window+R and type cmd to open command prompt console. so could I open such console to fire curl command.How to open such window? or which software or plugin do I need to install?. please suggest

Comment: this post already answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/how-do-i-install-set-up-and-use-curl-on-a-windows, but you can also use cygwin with the curl extension, it will emulate a linux console in your system In the Cygwin package manager, click on curl. Yes, it's that simple.

Comment: can you do curl request with plugin head? I am just able to do a post request. but curl requests looks different