# Getting error when I run vagrant up in puphpet

Tags: vagrant, puphpet

I am trying to set up vagrant locally on my Windows 10 machine, I have pre installed latest version of Vagant and Virtual box. I am trying to setup Ubuntu 14, Apache, PHP and Mysql. After downloading the package from puphpet.com, I CD in to the directory and trying to run `vagrant up`. I am getting the following error. I also tried with Centos, getting the same error

```
F:\puphpet (3)\MQLYog>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'local' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> local: Box 'puphpet/centos65-x64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    local: Box Provider: virtualbox
    local: Box Version: >= 0
The box '["puphpet/centos65-x64"]' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puphpet/centos65-x64"]
Error:
```

Answer (score 1):

hmm it looks like the name is correct, can you try to download the box separately :

```
vagrant box add puphpet/centos65-x64
```

if you have a SSL error you can run

```
vagrant box add puphpet/centos65-x64 --insecure
```

when prompted for the provider, select `virtualbox`

Comment: weird .. can you do `vagrant box add puphpet/centos65-x64 --force` and delete the boxXXX file from `.vagrant.d/tmp` directory

Comment: do you have issue only with this particular box or with any box from atlas ?

Comment: Earlier I installed Ubuntu with Vagrant, its working fine. Now when I am trying to install with puphpet and vagrant I am getting this error. I already have a linux box that is working fine.

Comment: ok can you try to download the box using `wget https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puphpet/boxes/centos65-x64/versions/20151130/providers/virtualbox.box` then add the box as `vagrant box add puphpet/centos65-x64 <path to downloaded file>`

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant comes with a own `curl.exe` on Windows, but this seems to be broken.

Try to install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

If it does not work, then try this way:

- Install a working curl.exe executable [Download](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win64)
- Make curl available for the whole system (PATH system-variable) [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/how-do-i-install-set-up-and-use-curl-on-a-windows/20773224#20773224)
- Delete or rename the unfunctional `curl.exe` in `C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\bin`