# Install php cURL on Windows Phpstorm

Tags: php, windows, curl, installation, phpstorm

How do you install the php curl extension on Windows for Phpstorm IDE? I would like to be able to run curl php functions on my local Windows 10 machine.

`extension=php_curl.dll` is uncommented in php.ini

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this : [INSTALL CURL ON WINDOWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/how-do-i-install-set-up-and-use-curl-on-a-windows)

No need add config for PHPStorm. If your windows know Curl you can use this in terminal of PHPStorm no problem.