# How to create connection in storage plugin of Apache Drill Programmatically in c#

Tags: c#, apache-drill

I want to add new connections in storage plugins through my code. Would you please tell how to add or configure connections in storage plugin programmatically in **c#**.

Is it possible to configure storage plugin connection through command prompt? If yes, how?

Comment: you can simply add it using Drill Web UI?

Comment: would you please give me some example..?

Comment: check : https://drill.apache.org/docs/plugin-configuration-basics/  Which plugin you want to add?

Comment: Hi.. I already go through this link.. but not found any code or anything for configuration throught c# code.. I want to connect sql server throught c# code (Not Through Web Console or Drill Web UI). Please help me out.. And Is it possible to configure connections throught command prompt (rather than Web Console or Drill Web UI).

Comment: I want to write this Configuration:         {
  "type": "jdbc",
  "driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
  "url": "jdbc:sqlserver://DEMO;databaseName=newdemo",
  "username": "sa",
  "password": "XXXXXX",
  "enabled": true
}                                 Through Programmatically.(in C#)

Comment: firstly, try to add this plugin from web ui so that you will be sure that it's working (try querying on some table of SQL server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out some solution for that:

```
           var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
           var postData = "name=" + name + "&config=" + config;
           var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
           request.Method = "POST";
           request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
           request.ContentLength = data.Length;
           using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
           {
               stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           }
           var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
           var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
           if (responseString != null)
           {
               var jsonObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseString);
               return jsonObject.result == "success";
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the drill's [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/plugin-configuration-basics/), you can add plugin:

- Using the Drill Web Console
- Storage Plugin REST API
- Bootstrapping a Storage Plugin (*for distributed environment*)

**Using WEB UI**

As per [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/plugin-configuration-basics/#using-the-drill-web-console),

Go to: http://localhost:8047/storage (*replace localhost bt IP/hostname if drill is running on remote machine*)

Add New Storage Plugin (say name **sql**) & click create.

Put config there:

```
{
  type: "jdbc",
  enabled: true,
  driver: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
  url:"jdbc:sqlserver://1.2.3.4:1433;databaseName=mydatabase",
  username:"user",
  password:"password"
}
```

It will return success if your credentials are right.

Check [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/rdbms-storage-plugin/#example-sql-server-configuration) for sql-server plugin.

**Note:** Make sure you added `sqljdbc41.4.2.6420.100.jar`  in `<drill-directory>/jars/3rdparty`

**Using REST API**

As per [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/plugin-configuration-basics/#storage-plugin-rest-api),

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"sql","config": { type: "jdbc", enabled: true, driver: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",url:"jdbc:sqlserver://1.2.3.4:1433;databaseName=mydatabase",username:"user", password:"password"}' http://localhost:8047/storage/sql.json
```

I guess there is no direct way to add plugin via C++ client. You can write code for POST request using C++.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your reply..... Please tell me Is it possible to configure storage plugins through command prompt.??

Comment: curl -X POST I mentioned in aswer can be fired from command prompt (I am sure about linux machines )

Comment: you are not referring  **drill shell** by command prompt. Right?

Comment: yes..i  am not referring drill shell by command prompt. But wht ab the window..? And would you please give me example.. how to use curl -X POST in cmd..

Comment: This may help you: http://serverfault.com/questions/483754/is-there-a-built-in-command-line-tool-under-windows-like-wget-curl

Comment: From java, I can use jars (e.g. jersey) to make REST call. I believe you can do that from C++ too. I am java developer, so mot much aware about C++.

Comment: Thanks Dev.. for giving valuable time.. :)

Comment: Would you please tell me when to run curl command in cmd..?     [Means after: sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local" or before running the drill.]..? When i type this command i am getting an error

Comment: you are posting your plugin details to `http://localhost:8047/storage/sql.json
`. This url will  be active when you start drill. So, you need to start drill (_using command you mentioned_). Then fire CURL command..:)

Comment: Are you able to connect to SQL server via JDBC using the same url, username,password you mentioned in drill plugin?

Comment: Yes.. I am able t connect sql server via JDBC.. & I have used same user and pwd..

Comment: Please tell after typing sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local"    ... What to do for achieving storage plugin through  cmd..?

Comment: you need to verify 2 things. 1. Drill is running or not (using `sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local" `  drill shell with appear. Try `show databases` to verify its running) 2. I am assuming username, password, schema name, etc are right for sql server (you must have verified). Try to add plugin from C++ code or command prompt later. Open drill web ui `localhost:8047` & add plugin (_I mentioned in answer_). Is it returning success?

Comment: Yes drill is running successfully. and from localhost:8047, i have successfully connected from sqlserver. & it also show the databases, amd i have successfully run the query from sqlserver.The only things i want to know that how (code)can i create new storage plugin from cmd.

Comment: you downloaded tool for running curl command on your windows machine?

Comment: No.. Which tool I have to download..? Please tell me..?

Comment: I did not use windows much. This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/how-do-i-install-set-up-and-use-curl-on-a-windows

Comment: Hi.. Would you please tell me why to use distribute mode and how to provide user name and password while starting the drill(For Security Purposes)

Comment: @NaveenD I suggest you to ask a different question as this is a different problem. Also, you will get views of different users on this concern.

Comment: I am trying to configure for Oracle DB. But showing: 

> Error(Not able to create and update storage.)

        {
      type: "jdbc",
      enabled: true,
      driver: "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
      url:"jdbc:oracle:thin:system/pass@123@1@192.XXX.XXX.XXX:8047:nvn"
    }

Please tell what i am doing wrong in this..?

Comment: I hope you added `ojdbc7.jar` in 3rdParty. Your jdbc url `url:"jdbc:oracle:thin:system/pass@123@1@192.XXX.XXX.XXX:8047:nvn" ` is incorrect. It should be like `"jdbc:oracle:thin:user/pass@192.168.41.67:1521:nvn"` where user & pass are username, password.

Comment: Ya I have already added ojdbc7.jar in 3rdParty.   And my connection is right.   system is my user name , pass@123 is my password.

Comment: & NVN is my workspace for oracle.. and can i used localhost instead of 192.168.41.41.67..?

Comment: I hope `pass@123@1` written above is by mistake..:P Are you able to connect to oracle with above mentioned credentials via JDBC client?

Comment: sorry password is pass@123 & Yes I am able to connect with this credentials

Comment: :- How to  write code for POST request using C++ for storage plugin. Please give some example..?