# Apache Drill Embedded And Distributed System

Tags: apache-drill

I am new in Apache Drill. I have gone through the Apache Drill official site and their documentation, but couldn't understand when to use Distribute system and when to use Embedded System.

I want to apply Drill in live project.So please give some advice which one to use (Embedded or Distributed) and how ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Embedded Mode:** This requires less configuration & it is preferred for testing purpose.

As per drill [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/embedded-mode-prerequisites/):

> Drill in embedded mode installs Drill locally on your machine. Embedded mode is a quick way to install and try Drill without having to perform any configuration tasks. A ZooKeeper installation is not required. Installing Drill in embedded mode configures the local Drillbit service to start automatically when you launch the Drill shell.

**Distributed Mode:** In this mode, drill runs on one or more nodes in a clustered environment. Running a ZooKeeper quorum is required.

As you asked, for live project you should use **distributed mode**. If you are using any hadoop cluster, you can install Drill on the same cluster. You need to install Drill on all the nodes. Check [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/installing-drill-on-the-cluster/) for more details.

**Edit:**

As you are new to Drill, for POC purpose you should use embedded mode.

- [Download](https://drill.apache.org/download/) Drill.
- Start Drill with command `bin/drill-embedded` (for linux). 
  For windows check [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/starting-drill-on-windows/).
- Add plugin through web UI
- Start Querying.

Comment: please give some explanation dev..?

Comment: Please go through documentation of apache drill (_I shared useful links in answer_) if you find any issue while installing or running stackoverflow is happy to help...:)

Comment: It would be better if you share your use case in brief in the question

Comment: I want to get data from different data sources(oracle, sql, mysql, etc) throught c# Programming. please suggest me which one to use(distributed or embedded)..??

Comment: would you please tell me about REST API. How can i used in Window. The doc which drill provide don't have any info about REST API for window. They give info about linux only. Would you please tell me how can i used REST API for programatically creating new storage plugin in window.

Comment: as I told you on your other answer. check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35308055/how-to-create-connection-in-storage-plugin-of-apache-drill-programmitically-in-c **READ COMMENTS TOO.**

Comment: I will tell you my live scenario:-  I have a web project, I want to use Apache Drill to fetch data from different Data Sources(DBs). For that I am using Web Application. My Question is. How Can I Used Drill in My Project. And If Some User Creating New Connection then New Storage Plugin Should be Created In Drill for That Connection through Code.

Comment: @SanjivKumar I guess you are able to achieve adding plugin via code. I saw your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36008584/3929393 So your problem solved

Comment: Ya dev I am able to achieve. But I want to know how to configure PAM authentication in window for drill

Comment: How to start drill in distributed mode in window

Comment: Go to the node on which drill is installed. Use `bin/drillbit.sh start`

Comment: I have very important doubt : whether Apache Drill only supports [dbo] schema?? or it will support all type of schema.  BECAUSE, I am trying to search with same storage plugin.. it work for [dbo] schema while other schema such as [core] its not working :: EXAMPLE:-- select * from SqlServer.dbo.Attribute;(Its Working). BUT select * from SqlServer.core.Users(its not working).??

Comment: :-- Do have any idea about this schema problem dev. I am running this query for SQL SERVER.

Comment: @SanjivKumar Do your user has permission to read data from core schema? It should work for all schemas

Comment: Ya it has permisssion

Comment: :-Is there any in drill to provide permission for schema..? Because all my schema has same type. There is no different b/w dbo and core schema. dbo is working but core is not working.. It showing table is not present.

Comment: @SanjivKumar I would say ask a different questions with plugin details, drill version, mode, OS details, etc. so that it will help the community.