# Cannot install curl on Windows 7

Tags: curl

I've been trying to install the cURL command line tool for Windows, but I'm blocked at the very beginning of the process...

On every tutorials I've seen, it says that we must download the curl package from https://curl.haxx.se, unzip it, and place the curl.exe file somewhere on the computer.

But where is this file?! I've downloaded several packages, but nowhere I can find this file...

What is wrong? Can someone help me please?
Many thanks!
Alfredo

Comment: Did you download [this file](https://dl.uxnr.de/build/curl/curl_winssl_cross_x64/curl-7.50.1/curl-7.50.1.zip)? Did you open the ZIP file? If so, where did you extract the contents?

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded this file. I have extracted everything in a directory on my desktop. But unfortunately, there's no "curl.exe" into it :(

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/how-do-i-install-set-up-and-use-curl-on-a-windows

Comment: The `curl.exe` program is in the `src` folder of the ZIP file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually downloaded it. There is a `curl.exe` file in the `src` folder. The path would be `src/curl.exe`.