# Curl on Windows

Tags: curl, libcurl

I have followed all on this link : [How do I install/set up and use cURL on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/how-do-i-install-set-up-and-use-curl-on-a-windows)

But I could not install latest curl 7.50.3 from https://curl.haxx.se/download.html. on windows 7 / 2008 Server R2

I have basically tried below
1. Download Win64 version
2. Unzip
3. Copy curl.exe under /src to C:\Windows (thats my %windir%)
4. Open cmd and type 'curl'

Below is the error im getting
c:\Curl\src>curl
curl:./.libs/lt-curl.c:233: FATAL: couldn't find curl.

I have also added the folder where I have unzipped curl in 'Path' env variable.

Comment: Any luck with this issue?

Comment: It might be easier to Git for Windows, which comes with a curl binary that'll just work - although you'll possibly need to add that directory to the path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with that version and also put it in my %windir%.
Instead I downloaded the latest version at https://sourceforge.net/projects/curlforwindows/files/?source=navbar and added curl to %PATH% on machine. Hope that helps.