# How to update cURL on windows?

Tags: curl

I have `cURL` installed on windows OS along with `git`.
Now I have to update the `cURL` version.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39726079/curl-on-windows) link, I downloaded the `cURL` latest version and added to the 
environment variable of the system.

But still `curl --version` gives me the previous version installed.How can I make new version to work out?

Comment: Are both versions in your path? Make sure there's only one. ALso make sure your path isn't too long.

Comment: @doctorlove I cannot find the  `cURL` path which came along with `git`.But `git` is in path.So that makes curl in that path too.What to do now?

Comment: When you type `where curl` what does it say? You might find it easier to explicitly state which curl you want to use if you have more than one

Comment: @doctorlove It points to the `git` installation dir where `cURL` is in bin folder.Does that mean I have to remove git path ?

Comment: @doctorlove it  works when I remove the `Git` path .

Comment: I have some cmd files to set the paths I need if I want to swap versions...

Comment: @doctorlove Is there any work around for this? I'll be using both `curl` and `git` together with some 3rd parties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `where` on windows to find which version is being used.

```
WHERE curl.exe
```

You could fully qualify the specific cURL version you want to invoke, or remove the wrong version from `PATH`.

Beware dumping everything in your PATH env variable - it's easier to set the path explicitly for the specific versions you want to use.

Try having a set_path.cmd file for each setup:

```
set PATH=[wherever_git_is];%PATH%
```

for when you want git and

```
set PATH=[other_curl];%PATH%
```

for when you want to use the other cURL.