# curl -i -H "Content-Type : Application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/courses

Tags: pycurl

I try to update the data of json file and use the command
curl -i -H "Content-Type : Application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/courses
but I got an error something like -
Invoke-WebRequest : Missing an argument for parameter 'InFile'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.
At line:1 char:6

- curl -i -H "Content-Type : Application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1 ...
- ```
   ~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Please correct me where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`curl` is not actually the normal UNIX `curl` in PowerShell.  It's an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`.

If you're using Windows 10, you can type `cmd.exe` before you run the `curl` command.  That will put you in the Windows Command Prompt, where, if you're on Windows 10, you can run the real `curl` utility.

You might need to see the notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7173011/16442705), since you're on Windows.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39726079/16442705).