# Passing API key with HTTP header in cURL

Tags: powershell, curl, apigee

I have an API Proxy in Apigee which is authenticated with an API key. I'm passing the key with my HTTP request header using cURL, with this command:

```
curl -v -H "apikey: my_key" http://api_org-test.apigee.net/v1/helloapikey
```

I get this error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the 
"apikey: my_key" value of type "System.String" to 
type "System.Collections.IDictionary".
```

When I  modify my policy to look for the key in query parameter rather than the header, it works fine.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try this:

```
curl -v -H @{'apikey' = 'my_key'} http://api_org-test.apigee.net/v1/helloapikey
```

---

**Note:** 
`curl` is an alias for the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet:

```
Get-Alias curl
```

**output:**

```
CommandType     Name
-----------     ----
Alias           curl -> Invoke-WebRequest
```

Comment: For multiple headers, multiple `-H` does not work, you need to use `-H @{'Cookies' = 'examplecookie=examplevalue'; 'Authorization: example'}`

Answer (score 16):

You could install curl:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16216825/3013633

Remove existing curl alias by executing this command:

`Remove-item alias:curl`

Then your command will work:

`curl -v -H "apikey: my_key" http://api_org-test.apigee.net/v1/helloapikey`

Comment: In my case curl was already installed. Only had to remove alias.

Answer (score 7):

None of the above answers worked for me (I got an error -- `parse error near }`).

This worked:

```
curl -X GET \
  'http://api_org-test.apigee.net/v1/helloapikey' \
  -H 'apikey: my_key'
```

Comment: @him299 How can I add this on a curl script. using Php?

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell simply does not resolve the variable within your URL. You are trying to query the service at the URI `http://$serverHost:1234/service` which won't work. You could do

```
$serverHost = "myHost"
$service = "http://$serverHost`:1234/service"
Invoke-WebRequest $service -Method Get
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add this to the discussion, I had to both hash the api key, but *leave* the token call key phrase rather than change it to 'apikey'. That's just what worked for me!

```
curl -v -H @{'X-API-TOKEN' = '[*insert key here*]'} '*datacenter_url*)'
```

Also noteworthy to PowerShell newcomers, -v stands for verbose. This switch gives you a Cyan-colored text under the command in PowerShell ise about the command PS is running. Almost like a play-by-play commentary. Useful enough I thought I'd mention it.