# CURL installation in windows unzip package missing .exe file

Tags: windows, curl

Where is the bin folder in the zip file that has been downloaded for the curl installation in windows 64.

I went to the below url and downloaded the zip file.

https://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin&os=Win64&flav=-&ver=*&cpu=x86_64

[image: downloadpage]

[image: unzip folder]

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing code. Requests for debugging user-level software installs, tutorials, research, tools,  recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @Shelter i have refered this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/how-do-i-install-set-up-and-use-curl-on-a-windows) where every one are taking about .exe file will be there in bin, am confused where it will be bcz i have tried all different downloads zip 7z for both windows OS flavours but still i dont find any .exe file.