# Difference between CURLAUTH_NEGOTIATE in PHP libcurl VS. --negotiate in cURL 7.57.0

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, windows-authentication

Can anyone shed some light on the different between CURLAUTH_NEGOTIATE in PHP libcurl (PHP 5.6.4 running on Windows with libcurl v7.39.0) and --negotiate in cURL 7.57.0?

**The following request using cURL 7.57.0 via the command line works:**

```
curl --negotiate -u MYDOMAIN\myuser:mypass  http://myip:myport/mywebservice.svc
```

**When I try the code below using PHP 5.6.4 (running on Windows) with libcurl v7.39.0 the remote web server returns a 401.2 error:**

```
<?php
//Set vars
$url = "http://myip:myport/mywebservice.svc"; // asmx URL of WSDL
$un = "myuser";  //  username
$password = "mypass"; // password
$domain = "MYDOMAIN\\"; // domain

//Create, Send and Output cURL Request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NEGOTIATE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  $domain . $un.":".$password);

$response = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $response;
?>
```

**Here are the PHP CURL Settings:**

```
cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.39.0
Age => 3
**Features**
AsynchDNS => Yes
CharConv => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => No
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
krb4 => No
Largefile => Yes
libz => Yes
NTLM => Yes
NTLMWB => No
SPNEGO => Yes
SSL => Yes
SSPI => Yes
TLS-SRP => No
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => i386-pc-win32
SSL Version OpenSSL/1.0.1i
ZLib Version => 1.2.7.3
libSSH Version => libssh2/1.4.3
```

Any insights are greatly appreciated! Thanks ~Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work around the problem stated above, I am just bypassing the libcurl used by PHP. I downloaded the latest version of cURL from https://curl.haxx.se/download.html (Our server is on windows, just FYI) and put it in an accessible directory.

Then simply wrote the following code:

```
<?php

//Set vars
$url = "http://<my_host_ip_or_domain>:<my_host_post_if_needed>/<my_path_etc>";
$userName = "DOMAIN\username";
$password = "password";
$filePath = "myxmlfile.xml";
$contentLength = strlen(file_get_contents($filePath));

//Set any curl args (other than headers) you wish - per https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html (These are the ones I needed to solve my particular authentication problem)
$curlSettings = array();
$curlSettings["--negotiate"] = '';
$curlSettings["-u"] = $userName .':'.  $password;
$curlSettings["--http1.1"] = '';
$curlSettings["--location-trusted"] = '';
$curlSettings["--post301"] = '';
$curlSettings["--data"] = '@"'. $filePath .'"';


//Set any cURL headers you want
$curlHeaders = array(
    'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Length: '. $contentLength,
    'SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/blahblahblah',
    'Host: <my_host_ip>:<my_host_port>'
);

//Call the function
$curlResp = curlRequest($url, $curlSettings, $curlHeaders);

//Output the result
echo '<pre>';
print_r($curlResp);
echo '</pre>';


//Handle cURL Request
function curlRequest($url,$args,$headers)
{   
    /*
        Note: This needs to be the full path to CURL on server or you can set it to run as a windows cmd (as I have), 
        by following the instructions outlined by Michiel van Oosterhout in the following post: 
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/how-do-i-install-set-up-and-use-curl-on-windows 
    */
    $strCurl = "curl";

    //Add Args / Setting to cURL request
    foreach ($args as $key => $val)
    {
        $strCurl .= " ". $key ." ". $val;
    }

    //Add headers to cURL request
    foreach ($headers as $h)
    {
        $strCurl .= ' --header "'. $h .'"';
    }

    //Set the URL
    $strCurl .= " ". $url;

    //Execute the curl request
    exec($strCurl, $resp);

    //Return an array of the response
    return $resp;
}

?>
```

Works like a charm!