# downloading csv file works via libcurl yet does not via curl method

Tags: r, curl, download, libcurl

OS: Win 7 64 bit
RStudio Version 1.1.463

As per Getting and Cleaning Data course, I attempted to download a *csv* file with  *method = curl*:

```
fileUrl <- "https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/dz54-2aru/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"
download.file(fileUrl, destfile = "./cameras.csv", method = "curl")
```

> Error in download.file(fileUrl, destfile = "./cameras.csv", method =
>   "curl") :    'curl' call had nonzero exit status

However, `method = libcurl` resulted a successful download:

```
download.file(fileUrl, destfile = "./cameras.csv", method = "libcurl")
```

> trying URL
>   'https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/dz54-2aru/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD'
>   downloaded 9443 bytes

changing from *http***s** to *http* produced exactly the same results for `curl` and `libcurl`, respectively.

Is there anyway to make this download work via `method = curl` as per the course?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there were a few issues here:
Followed the steps in the link quoted by @JonnyCrunch

a) Reinstalled Git for windows;

b) added C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\ to the 'PATH' variable;

c) Disabled *Use Internet Explorer library/proxy for HTTP* in *RStudio* in: Tools > Options > Packages

d) Attempted steps in 'e)' below and added [data.baltimorecity.gov](https://data.baltimorecity.gov)
*website to exclusions* as per Kaspersky anti-virus' prompt;

e) Then in RStudio:

```
options(download.file.method = "curl")

download.file(fileUrl, destfile="./data/cameras.csv")
```

Success!

Thank you

Comment: Why are you going to all this trouble? The point of having different download options is so that if one doesn't work, you can try another. Since `method="libcurl"` worked, your problem is solved right there

Comment: Tried to get 'curl' method to work as per the specs in the course and get to the bottom of root causes. Jumping from one method to another, using 'http', as opposed to 'https' like in other similar posts, does not solve the actual problem.

Comment: "Jumping from one method to another" _solved the actual problem_ of downloading the file.

Comment: "Jumping from one method to another" did not solve the issue of following course's instructions and did not get "curl" method to work in my environment. there would not have been "curl" method, or any other any other download method, had it not offered its own advantages of using it, right?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from `?download.file`:

> For methods "wget" and "curl" a system call is made to the tool given
>   by method, and the respective program must be installed on your system
>   and be in the search path for executables. They will block all other
>   activity on the R process until they complete: this may make a GUI
>   unresponsive.

Therefore, you should install `curl`first.
See this [How do I install and use curl on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/how-do-i-install-and-use-curl-on-windows) to learn how. 
Best!