# How to configure a proxy into GitBash environment on windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows, proxy, environment-variables, git-bash

I installed Python 3.7.3 on windows 10, but I can't install Python packages via PIP in Gitbash (Git SCM), due to my company's internet proxy.

I tryed to create environment variables for the proxy via the following, but it didn't work:

- export http_proxy='proxy.com:8080'
- export https_proxy='proxy.com:8080'

I found a temporary solution that works for me: inserting the following aliases into the .bashrc file:

- alias python='winpty python.exe'
- alias pip='pip --proxy=proxy.com:8080'

The above is working but I am looking for a nicer solution so that I don't need to set aliases for every command I use. I was thinking about something like an environment variable but didn't found out how to set it up on a windows' git bash environment yet.

Do you have an idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need Git bash to `pip install` Python modules.
Only Git path (to use linux-like commands, plus `curl`, even though [it is available on recent Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50200838/6309)), from a regular CMD, with a simplified `PATH`:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
set PH=C:\path\to\Python37
set PATH=%PH%;%PH%\Scripts
```

Second, you can `pip install` in a corporate environment, provided:

- you access your proxy through `px`, an HTTP proxy server to automatically authenticate through an NTLM proxy
- you use and trust mirror alternatives for pip module sources.

Regarding [`genotrance/px`](https://github.com/genotrance/px), simply run the service with `px --proxy=my.company.prpxy:<port> --save --config=/path/to/your/px.ini`

No need to enter your credentials (Windows log/password): the proxy uses your current login session.

Set your environment variable to reference that proxy:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:3128
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:3128
```

Then, this will work:

```
λ pip install -i http://pypi.mirror.frontiernet.net/simple --trusted-host pypi.mirror.frontiernet.net "ansible-tower-cli==3.2.1" --force-reinstall
Looking in indexes: http://pypi.mirror.frontiernet.net/simple
Collecting ansible-tower-cli==3.2.1
  Downloading http://pypi.mirror.frontiernet.net/packages/98/39/566f2dc628917e28d6600607cd0a533b9ed02395297363b2db827e59e488/ansible-tower-cli-3.2.1.tar.gz (153kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 107kB/s
```

(Use any pypi mirror not blocked by your company=

Comment: to avoid a so long `pip install -i xyz --trusted-host xyz` it is possible to use a var env used by pip on windows to inform  pip that localhost:3128 is the Web proxy ?

Comment: @user3313834 Yes: I have edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

first you need to check if the corp Proxy you are behind is NTLM or not, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379/3313834 may help.