# Error installing curl in Visual studio 2019

Tags: windows-10, libcurl, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to run curl programs in visual studio 2019 (in windows 10 64 bits). I tried to run the following command in Visual Studio Developer command , but it seems i am making some mistake . Can someone tell me what it is and how to resolve it ?

1)  https://drive.google.com/open?id=19Raed8zuAFW7-8s029bHP5oN6qEmOO_8

ERROR WINDOW :

1) https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XcNUxmOihqSinVBPRfsN95nbouccL4Ws

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any installer for curl. You simply download a zip and use it.

Please refer to the question, may be it will help: [How do I install and use curl on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/how-do-i-install-and-use-curl-on-windows)