# Using required CURL extension to install Valet

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to install Valet on my laravel 6 project. So when I run `composer global require cretueusebiu/valet-windows` to install it, I get the following error:

> requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

However, extension=curl is enable in my php.ini file and also I run following command to check whether it is enable or nor:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

There also I can see the curl support is enable. What should I do to use Valet now? I am using Windows 10 and according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/how-do-i-install-and-use-curl-on-windows/50200838#50200838), there is curl.exe but it does nothing with my expected answer.

and when I run `php -m` I get the following:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
tidy
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

So there is no curl available. What do I do to get it?

Comment: Run `php -m`, and check whether **ext-curl** is available there!

Comment: ext-curl is not available when I run `php -m`

Answer (score 0):

**ext-curl** might not be enabled.

Try to enable:

```sh
$ sudo phpenmod curl
```

OR, install:

```sh
$ sudo apt install php[7.2,7.3]-curl
```

Repalce **[7.2,7.3]** from your installed PHP's version

> You can use your OS package manager. Here I've used Aptitude for Debian

Comment: Will I be able to use sudo on windows OS?

Comment: If you're on WSL, else go with same medium you had installed PHP and it's extensions. Simply google :)