# Troubleshooting with MetaboAnalyst

Tags: r

I am trying to run MetaboAnalyst 3.0.3 Pathway Analysis on R (see session information below), and I am getting an error when I try to run the second line of code.

[Pathway Analysis Tutorial](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CXluzyYqNoPqu1DI3HwvDAmRVGMe825m/view)

I keep getting this error:

```
> mSet<-InitDataObjects(data.type = "conc", anal.type = "pathora", FALSE)
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

[Session Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub8g6.png)

I tried following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62119835/how-do-i-overcome-issues-with-metaboanalyst-in-r-when-trying-to-run-pathway-anal) but will no luck. I would really appreciate guidance on this seemingly trivial problem!

Comment: Have you tried updating each of the packages required in MetaboAnalystR? : `pacman::p_load("impute", "pcaMethods", "globaltest", "GlobalAncova", "Rgraphviz", "preprocessCore", "genefilter", "SSPA", "sva", "limma", "KEGGgraph", "siggenes","BiocParallel", "MSnbase", "multtest","RBGL","edgeR","fgsea","httr","qs")`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I did try that and unfortunately I get the same error. I am not sure if the dependencies that I have loaded are messing with MetaboAnalyst. Any other insights would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at this, it seems the same problem of you occurs, maybe related to a problem with a package ! : https://github.com/xia-lab/MetaboAnalystR/issues/16