# Install Python + Django in Batch script

Tags: python, batch-file

I want to have a script for Windows users to install Python, run `python -m venv env` and `pip install -r requirements.txt` and `python manage.py runserver`.

Installing Python is the part I'm really unsure about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run python installer in the background via simple command.

Example: (For reference see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html).)

```
python-installer.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1
```

If you also want to download the python installer you can use `curl`. (It is available on Windows 10 version 1803 or later. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16216825/9776840).)

If you want to have everything inside one .bat script, you also want to refresh system environmental variables after the installation process. Via script like [this](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/master/src/chocolatey.resources/redirects/RefreshEnv.cmd). So you can simply use `python` and `pip`. Or you can just use absolute paths.

Example script would look like:

```
@echo off

rem --Download python installer
curl "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.4/python-3.9.4-amd64.exe" -o python-installer.exe

rem --Install python
python-installer.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1

rem --Refresh Environmental Variables
call RefreshEnv.cmd

rem --Use python, pip
python -m venv env
pip install -r requirements.txt
python manage.py runserver

pause
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain a bit more about why I'll want to refresh system environment variables? Could there be any unintended side effects after doing so?

Comment: In my example the installer modifies the `PATH` environmental variable by adding the python install directory and python Scripts directory there, but it does not update the variable for the current command prompt session. You would either have to write full path to python and pip executables or restart the command prompt. The `RefreshEnv.cmd` script pulls the variables from the system registry and resets them in the current command prompt session. As far as I know there shouldn't be any side effects.