# Dart : At the end of the tutorial, I don't know how to check that the app is working

Tags: dart

https://dartfrog.vgv.dev/docs/tutorials/todos#summary
I got to this section, but I don't know how to get it to work at the end, so I can't get it to work.

in my browser

```
http://localhost:8080/todos
```

When I access the above url, [] is displayed, so I think it's working.

---

```
# Update a specific todo by id
curl --request PUT \
  --url http://localhost:8080/todos/<id> \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "title": "Take out trash!",
  "isCompleted": true
}'
```

How can I check that the above part works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line you see there is a command you are supposed to run on your commandline.

If you use a newer version of windows you probably have `curl` already, if not, see [How do I install and use cURL on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/how-do-i-install-and-use-curl-on-windows)

So you open your command prompt and enter

```
curl --request PUT --url http://localhost:8080/todos/<id> --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{ "title": "Take out trash!", "isCompleted": true }'
```

where I guess the `<id>` part needs to be an id. So for example `1`.

Please note that that is a tutorial for a *backend* in Dart. They are not commonly called an app. If you are looking to build a nice app for your device or webbrowser, with ui controls like input boxes and buttons, you are reading the wrong tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Looks like I didn't realize it already worked.
I would like to proceed with the package selection according to your advice.