# How to install cURL in 32-bit Windows?

Tags: windows, curl

How to install cURL in 32-bit Windows?

When I follow
[Run cURL commands from Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710748/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console) I get this problem:

[image: Error]

Comment: You downloaded the win64 version - its right there in the install path - get the win32 installer instead

Comment: can u suggest me any link for it ?

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin

Answer (score 0):

Had less experience use Curl in windows, but from your error, seems that your curl was not installed probably, So you can try to install another version libcurl for your system.

Answer (score 0):

Installing a 32-bit cURL on Windows is pretty easy. You can even just follow a step-by-step procedure with screenshots. You can follow the instructions from **[Making cURL work on Windows 7](http://blog.abelcallejo.com/2013/09/making-curl-work-on-windows-7.html)**. There are instructions there for both 32-bit and 64-bit installations.

Answer (score 0):

If you have git installed, the curl commands can be run from git bash.