# In Haskell, how can I write an HTTP client to traverse a website and submit forms?

Tags: haskell

I'm pretty sure [Network Browser](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTTP/4000.2.8/doc/html/Network-Browser.html) is the library I want to use, but I'm not sure how to use it.  I'm a Haskell newbie.  I've read Learn You A Haskell and 1/3rd of Real World Haskell.

I want to write a program that visits a website, logs in to it (which would require submitting a form and cookies), and then gives me the HTML of some pages.

I'd like to see some examples of how to do these things.  The documentation only gives one example.  Also, please teach a man to fish.  If there some other place I should be looking to find examples (IMO the best way to learn how to use a library) I'd like to know.  Reading the api documentation isn't cutting it.

*Side note:* [This library named Shpider looks perfect](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shpider-0.2.1.1), but I'm on windows and I can't figure out how to install and use curl which is one of the libraries it depends on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2710748/784338 To get cUrl

Comment: @jozefg: I was going to try that soon.  I already tried it with http-wget by installing it on cygwin and now when I use wget commands they just hang in winghci.

Comment: I found curl didn't work well with the intranet I was crawling, because it uses a lot of state cookie and weird page updates, but selinium (which has a haskell binding somewhere) did.