# Testing RESTful web API application with return codes

Tags: web-services, api, rest, return, web-testing

I have a RESTful web API application that consists of several URL calls that return XML content. These tests would consist of (my) declared query string parameters and methods, such as POST, GET, HEAD...

I would like to fully automate the testing of these services in the most simple way possible. It would also be a great benefit if this wouldn't cause any additional costs.

The possibility of saving these tests with my given parameters for later use (to test further API upgrades or changes) would be perfect.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their answers, I really appreciate it. I also apologize for any inconsistencies in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [HttpMaster](http://www.httpmaster.net/).
It allows you to define dynamic parameters and use them for URL paths or request body. You can then run multiple customized requests in a batch and review responses (with http return codes, of course).
It's quite intuitive with nice GUI and, the most important, it's free. It is also capable to save created tests to a project file.
But it's a standalone tool (not running in a browser), you did not state what type of tool would you prefer (browser or stand-alone).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The GUI doesn't really matter that much to me. Saving my projects for future testing and the fact that it's free is a definite win for me. I know I didn't specify my needs (software or browser add-on/plugin), but I prefer software any day. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm handling it is by HTTP status codes. I map whatever HTTP status codes available to my API to make more sense out of it. In addition I return a JSON payload which carries more verbose message regarding the error and a helpful link to my docs for the developer.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I'm in search of a tool for testing my RESTful web API application. A tool that would enable me to declare a query string parameter and/or method (POST, GET...). You can imagine a range of URLS being used, and I'd like to know what they return, instead of manually checking them one by one.

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.soapui.org/ Or you can make a text file of the URLs you want to check and pass them one by one to CURL and log the responses OR the most proper one, write a unit test!

Comment: SoapUI seems like the thing (free download option + saving projects for later use), but it's a little bit too feature packed for my needs. Second best choice, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do one off testing with Postman: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

You can also do one off testing with curl: [Run cURL commands from Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710748/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console)

Postman sounds exactly like what you're looking for.

Comment: Postman sounds like something I'm searching for, but the fact I have to use it as an "add-on" is a show stopper for me. I clearly didn't specify what type of tool (standalone or add-on/plugin) I imagined, and I apologize for that. Thank you very much for your assistance and suggestions.