# How to use GET to fetch list of repositories?

Tags: git, github, github-api

I am not able to understand how the below thing works: I run the "`GET /orgs/octokit/repos`" command in the terminal and nothing happens.
It's supposed to get list of repositories. I am sure I am not doing the correct way. Can somebody please explain why this command doesn't work?

Example: When you get a list of repositories, you get the summary representation of each repository.
Here, we fetch the list of repositories owned by the octokit organization:

```
GET /orgs/octokit/repos
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET is supposed to be an [HTTP request method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods), not a command.

See for example this [`curl` tutorial](https://gist.github.com/caspyin/2288960), as a way to do some GET through [`curl`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL).

```
curl https://api.github.com/orgs/octokit/repos
```

This works also directly from your browser:

https://api.github.com/orgs/octokit/repos

Comment: Note: curl is included in Git if you are on Windows (http://stackoverflow.com/q/2710748/6309)

Comment: Thank you @VonC. I have to actually find all the commits done on a repository and then compare every alternate commit and output the diffs in a file. I think I have to try something like this - curl https://api.github.com/orgs/octokit/repos/commits/

Comment: @VonC I also have similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389414/how-to-create-organization-name-through-github-api-instead-of-creating-manually) on github-api. If possible can you help me out over there. I did some research but not able to find the answer for that.

Answer (score 2):

`GET` is not a command, it is the HTTP request method.  You will need to use something like curl.  This returns the list:

```
curl https://api.github.com/orgs/octokit/repos
```

You can also test that URL directly in your browser.

Comment: Thanks! I have to actually find all the commits done on a repository and then compare every alternate commit and output the diffs in a file.