# How can I get details of Projects hosted on Apache Projects Programatically (Do we have API)?

Tags: java, apache

I want to get details of a project that is hosted on Apache Projects.

Is there any API support where I get say, list of Java Projects (or) Given a project id get all issues related to particular project?

I did this for projects hosted on GitHub using its API but I am new to Apache Projects and couldn't find any such API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how those Apache projects are hosted (An apache httpd server alone, for instance, doesn't have any API to list those projects).

For Apache, those projects are mirrored on GitHub, which means you can use the [GitHub API on repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories) to [list the repos of the organization Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28268370/6309)

https://api.github.com/orgs/apache/repos

That URL will return plenty of details for each Apache project (incuding a field `"language": "Java"`), and you can filter said URL answer in order to keep only the projects you want to see.