# How to write Javascript HTTP GET request outside of browser (in Windows PC)

Tags: javascript, http, browser, get

I am trying to write a javascript function that can perform a HTTP Get request EXTERNAL TO A BROWSER. The javascript file will need to be executed in a windows program (Isadora). The reason is because I need to send data to www.google-analytics.com from the windows program (Isadora). Is this possible? And how can it be done?

Code examples would be greatly greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use curl read http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

Comment: @Cyril, nowadays programmer goes with scripts rather than learning the basics I suppose. :/

Comment: @Cyril I have looked through that document before, but was unable to find a working solution. which specific lines of code are you referring to? (Bear in mind that I have no curl, and minimal javascript experience. Thank you ;)

Comment: Ok I have least experience of windows programming but i am sure you can do curl something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710748/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console

Comment: You can also use [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)

Comment: Check the forum for Isadora, imo.

Comment: Thanks for your replies Cyril, but what I'm really after is a code example that is known to work. I looked at your link for curl, but it doesn't seem to have any connection to javascript.

Comment: @Ziki Thanks for your reply Ziki. I have already downloaded wget, but was unable to figure out how to use it in a javascript file. Would you be so kind as to share your knowledge to answer my original question?

Comment: @James I have looked in the isadora forum and the javascript function is only used for basic input manipulation etc. I'm trying to use the javascript file as a trigger for sending an event to google analytics.

Comment: Take a look at this: [execute-shell-command-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880198/how-to-execute-shell-command-in-javascript), then simply use wget or whatever else.

Comment: I'm not convinced Isadora supports Javascript for that use.  [This page](http://www.dusxproductions.com/blog/web-apis-in-isadora-part-1/) might help.