# PHP run curl using exec

Tags: php, linux, curl, exec

I tried running a curl command in php using exec method, it worked
well in my Linux server, but not working in my Windows machine, I checked
my PHP configuration file too, curl is enabled there. What could be the issue
that it is not working ?

My command is (one used for Linux - this one ran succesfully there)
'curl -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type:image/tiff" --data-binary @/opt/lampp/htdocs/PDAN_Dev/Admin/uploads/tif/'.$data_set_name.'.tif http://localhost:8080/geoedge/rest/workspaces/geoedge/coveragestores/'.$data_set_name.'/file.geotiff'

The one I ran in Windows

exec("curl -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H Content-type:image/tiff --data-binary C:/Users/Developer/Desktop/geoedge-test12.tif http://107.167.186.125:8080/geoedge/rest/workspaces/geoedge/coverageStores/geoedge-test13/file.geotiff")

When I ran it in the command prompt it gives me no output

Comment: This question will be easier to answer if you give details about the curl command you successfully ran and the errors you are getting now.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710748/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console

Comment: Or this? http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have not installed curl on your windows machine. PHP curl is not same thing as machine installed curl. When you are checking php configuration, it shows modules installed for php, not for machine.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run curl using the `exec` function, but with the [build in php functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php).

It's not because the php curl extension is installled that this library is installed globaly on your windows machine.