# Silent VB Script?

Tags: vbscript, background, automation, browser, background-process

I am attempting to write a script that operates in the background. This is only the early stages of the final project. But I am having difficulty getting this to run without opening the web browser. How can I get it to run in the background, unnoticed by the user?

```
Option Explicit
Dim wsh
Set wsh=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsh.Run "http://google.com"
```

Comment: please describe your *real world* problem. Obviously you don't want to start the default browser to show Google's start page (that's what your code is perfect for and that can't be done 'in the background'). Do you want to test whether Google is accessible (without bothering the user)? Do you want to access information on a page and store it in a database? ... Please tell us.

Comment: I am eventually wanting to login to the site and navigate to a specific page to see if there have been any changes. I'm only worrying about the logging in and navigating to the page at this point in the project.

Comment: Start your research here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204759/http-get-in-vbs