# Is there and automation (OLE2)-enabled HTTP Client that ships with Windows?

Tags: windows, abap

Is there an automation-enabled HTTP client (i.e. something I can control with an OLE client) that ships with Windows, and which I can assume is present on most versions of Windows?

I intend to use this in an SAP ABAP program from where I want to give the user an option to download data via their desktop connection rather than initiating the request from the SAP server.

I was thinking of seeing whether I can make OLE calls to Internet Explorer in this case (though I am not sure whether I can retrieve the response of an HTTP request), but I somehow think that such a client would somehow be 'cleaner'.

Comment: OLE is dead as a doornail.  Automation is a subset of COM, be sure to use proper terminology.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, though I am still not sure I understand the difference, and based on the Wikipedia entry for "OLE Automation" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_Automation) it seems that Microsoft never provided consistent definitions to begin with, and this has carried over e.g. into the SAP documentation I have referenced (which dates back about 12 years).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, while typing this question, I Googled for "vbscript http request" and the following Stack Overflow question answers my question by pointing to `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` as the object I would instantiate via OLE: [HTTP GET in VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204759/http-get-in-vbs)

Using this answer, we can write some ABAP code as follows:

```
data: httpclient type ole2_object.
data: response type string.

create object httpclient 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP' no flush.

call method of httpclient 'open' no flush
  exporting
    #1         = 'GET'
    #2         = 'http://www.google.co.za'
    #3         = 0.
call method of httpclient 'send'.

get property of httpclient 'responseText' = response.
```

After the last `GET PROPERTY`, the response string variable contains the body of the HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't class CL_HTTP_CLIENT work for your case? Using OLE Automation makes your program not very stable to my experience.

Comment: Like I said, it's for the case where I want the HTTP request to be sent from the user's desktop, and not from the SAP server (which will most likely be firewalled anyway, whereas the user is probably authenticated on a corporate proxy already).

Answer (score 0):

use HTTP_POST or HTTP_GET functions. there is a RFC_DESTINATION parameter. use value SAPHTTP to access site via user's desktop SAPHTTPA to do so via SAP server.

Comment: Thanks, that is an interesting solution, but it does not work for me. I can verify the RFC destionation SAPHTTP, but calling the function and specifying the destination parameter as 'SAPHTTP' results in a timeout.